# Is there a shorter proof to this Coq theorem?

Tags: coq

I'm learning to use Coq and I try to prove the theorems of a paper I'm reading. The paper is Having a Part Twice Over of Karen Bennett, published in 2013. The paper propopes a mereological theory composed of two primitives F and Ps and defines the parthood relation P using the two primitives.

I coded it as follows:

```
Class Entity: Type.

(* Slot Mereology defines the parthood relation
 * with the two primitives F and Ps.
 * The idea is that wholes have slots
 * filled by their parts.
 * F x s means that x fills slot s.
 * Ps s y means that s is a parthood slot of y.
 * P is the parthood relation.
 *)
Parameter F : Entity -> Entity -> Prop.
Parameter Ps : Entity -> Entity -> Prop.
Definition P (x y : Entity) :=
  exists s, F x s /\ Ps s y.

(* Slot Inheritance *)
Axiom A5 : forall x y z1 z2 : Entity,
  (Ps z1 y /\ F x z1) /\ Ps z2 x -> Ps z2 y.

(* Parthood Transitivity *)
Theorem T7 : forall x y z : Entity,
  (P x y /\ P y z) -> P x z.
Proof.
  intros x y z.
  unfold P.
  intro h.
  destruct h as (EsPxy, EsPyz).
  destruct EsPxy as (s1, Pxy).
  destruct Pxy as (Fxs1, Pss1y).
  destruct EsPyz as (s2, Pyz).
  destruct Pyz as (Fys2, Pss2z).
  exists s1.
  split.
  apply Fxs1.
  apply A5 with (z1 := s2) (x := y).
  split.
  split.
  assumption.
  assumption.
  assumption.
Qed.
```

I succeeded to prove theorem T7. I have two questions:

- is my Coq code ok? (I'm not sure If the way I declared the type, the primitives and the predicate is the right way to do it.)
- is there a shorter proof? (About the length of the proof, I only want to know about the number of tactics.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your Coq code is OK. But there are shorter proofs. This theorem is simple enough that it can be solved with Coq's automation tactics. E.g.,

```
Parameter Entity: Type.

(* Slot Mereology defines the parthood relation
 * with the two primitives F and Ps.
 * The idea is that wholes have slots
 * filled by their parts.
 * F x s means that x fills slot s.
 * Ps s y means that s is a parthood slot of y.
 * P is the parthood relation.
 *)
Parameter F : Entity -> Entity -> Prop.
Parameter Ps : Entity -> Entity -> Prop.
Definition P (x y : Entity) :=
  exists s, F x s /\ Ps s y.

(* Slot Inheritance *)
Axiom A5 : forall x y z1 z2 : Entity,
  (Ps z1 y /\ F x z1) /\ Ps z2 x -> Ps z2 y.

(* Parthood Transitivity *)
Theorem T7 : forall x y z : Entity,
  (P x y /\ P y z) -> P x z.
Proof.
unfold P; firstorder; eauto 10 using A5.
Qed.
```

(Notice that I replaced "Class Entity" with "Parameter Entity": The first form is actually just defining a type whose elements are records with no fields, whereas the second one is postulating that the type `Entity` exists without placing any further constraints on it.)

Comment: Thank you! I’m not sure to understand the proof, but I will look at the tactics. And thanks for the Entity explanation.

Comment: I looked at the tactics, and I don’t understand the value 10 after "eauto" tactic. What does it mean?

Comment: @Lepticed the number parameter of `eauto` is a bound on the number of applications that it will look for: the higher the value, the more goals it can solve potentially, but also the longer it takes.

Comment: @Lepticed you should be able to use `info_eauto` to have Coq print out what it used to solve the goal.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach, using ssreflect and its neat notation for destructuring, one can rephrase your explicit proof in a more compact way (I'm using Arthur's version).

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Parameter Entity: Type.

Parameter F : Entity -> Entity -> Prop.
Parameter Ps : Entity -> Entity -> Prop.
Definition P (x y : Entity) :=
  exists s, F x s /\ Ps s y.

Axiom A5 : forall x y z1 z2 : Entity,
  (Ps z1 y /\ F x z1) /\ Ps z2 x -> Ps z2 y.

Theorem T7 : forall x y z : Entity,
  (P x y /\ P y z) -> P x z.
Proof.
move=> x y z [[s1 [Fxs1 Ps1y]] [s2 [Fys2 Ps2z]]].
by exists s1; split; [|exact: (A5 y z s2 s1)].
Qed.
```